# Using method of Frobenius to find linearly independent solutions

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, frobenius-method

I have been given the equation $$y'' -2xy' +(\mu)y = 0 $$ where $\mu$ is a fixed parameter $\geq0$. I solve it with $x_{0} = 0$.

After plugging in $y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n} $ into the equation above, I equate the coefficients to $0$:

$$a_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2) + a_{n}(\mu - 2n) = 0$$

I am hoping this is correct.

From this I get the recurrence relation (which I also hope is correct):

$$a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n}(\mu -2n)}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$$

I expand and get some terms:

$$a_{2}=\frac{a_{0}(\mu)}{(1)(2)}$$

$$a_{3}=\frac{a_{1}(\mu - 2)}{(1)(2)(3)}$$

$$a_{4}=\frac{a_{0}(\mu)(\mu - 4)}{(1)(2)(3)(4)}$$

and so on.

How do I find the first three non-zero terms of each series?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Erm... you just did. Did you want to find the general term for the sequence? If so I believe recurrences of this form can be solved with ratios of gamma functions.

Comment: But does for each series mean for the even and odd integers of (n+2)? Since the answer is a combination of the two linearly independent solutions? @K.defaoite

Comment: I assume there is a typo and the equation is $y'' - 2 x y' + \mu y = 0$. Then the recurrence relation is
$$a_{n + 2} = \frac {(2 n - \mu) a_n} {(n + 1) (n + 2)}$$
with arbitrary $a_0$ and $a_1$ (in general there might be additional relations for the initial terms). That gives two linearly independent solutions.